# AWS missing file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

When trying to use deleteObjects() or deleteMatchingObjects() from AWS PHP SDK S3Client class, I get the following error:

```
include([cut]/src/Aws/S3/Command/DeleteMultipleObjects.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I investigated a little and such file doesn't even exist within the whole project repository + checked directly: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/src/Aws/S3/Command . The file isn't there.

However - it's quite hard to believe such thing hasn't been noticed yet. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in PHP you would use the S3Client and the method deleteObjects to accomplish what you're looking for (assuming you have the keys).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_deleteObjects

Alternatively you could use deleteMatchingObjects to delete objects using a regex search:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_deleteMatchingObjects